# Showing HTML Elements based on current Angular Route

Tags: angularjs, ng-show, route-provider

I am trying to add three additional list items based on the routeProvider. If the reports route is navigated to, I want to use ng-show to make three more list items visible. I want them to remain visible unless the create user or manage user route is navigated to. The new list items are access reports and details reports.

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li>
        <a href="#createUser"> Create User</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#manageUsers"> Manage Users</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#reports"> Reports</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

routeProvider.js

```
adminApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider

    .when('/createUser', {
        templateUrl : 'app/components/admin/views/createUserView.html',
        controller  : 'createUserController'
    })

    .when('/manageUsers', {
        templateUrl : 'app/components/admin/views/manageUsersView.html',
        controller  : 'manageUsersController'
    })

    .when('/editUser', {
        templateUrl : 'app/components/admin/views/editUserView.html',
        controller  : 'manageUsersController'
    })

    .when('/reports', {
        templateUrl : 'app/components/admin/views/reportsView.html',
        controller  : 'reportsController'
    })

    .when('/reports', {
        templateUrl : 'app/components/admin/views/accessReportsView.html',
        controller  : 'reportsController'
    })

    .when('/reports', {
        templateUrl : 'app/components/admin/views/detailsReportView.html',
        controller  : 'reportsController'
    })
```

I am trying to do something like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li>
        <a href="#createUser"> Create User</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#manageUsers"> Manage Users</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#reports"> Reports</a>
    </li>
    <!--show this list item if the route is /reportsView or /accessReportsView orsummaryReportsView-->
    <li>
        <a ng-show="" href="#reports"> Access Reports</a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

[Link git repo if needed](https://github.com/weswhite/admin-spa)

Comment: Look into [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) which could give you the current path and could be used to add/remove items to the array based on the path. There is many way of doing this though.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like as per you current configuration you should have `#/` in your anchors `href` attribute

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li>
        <a href="#/createUser"> Create User</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#/manageUsers"> Manage Users</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#/reports"> Reports</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by this. Could you further explain?

Comment: means your url won't work when clicked, but it doesn't answer your question of how to display some items based on the route selected.